# Implementing a Least Squares Kernel classifier

Tags: matrix, regression, svm, least-squares

I am trying to find the equation I would need to use in order to implement a Least Squares Kernel classifier for a dataset with N samples of feature length d. I have the kernel equation k(x_i, x_j) and I need the equation to pug it into to get the length-d vector used to classify future data. No matter where I look/google, Although there are dozens of powerpoints and pdfs that seem to give me almost what I'm looking for, I can't find a resource which can give me a straight answer.

note: I am not looking for the programming-language tool that computes this for me such as lsqlin, but the mathematical formula.

Answer (score 0):

Least Squares Kernel SVM (what I assume your actually asking about) is equivalent to Kernelized Ridge Regression. This is the simplest what to implement it, and the solution can be found [here](http://www.cs.berkeley.edu/~bartlett/courses/281b-sp08/10.pdf), assume you have the appropriate background.